# Tableau isn't converting my csv data source to tables

Tags: csv, tableau-api

When I import a csv to Tableau, it gets the same format of the original csv file (a single column with every label on it). How can I make Tableau separate the columns based on commas?
I can't see why this is happening, since in every tutorial I checked Tableau already converts the .csv to a tabular format.

[Here's what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yFcf.jpg)

Note: I'm using Tableau's trial version.

Comment: Yeah, that shouldn't happen. Theres most likely a formatting error or something that Tableau isn't expecting in the CSV. Have you tried converting the .csv to .xlsx to test?

Comment: Check the format of the CSV in a text editor (and it might help to post that result here).

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes when you open a csv in Excel it can mess with the formatting like your image shows. If you think you opened it in Excel before connecting, try downloading your source again and connecting first with Tableau. If that doesn't work, I happen to have this dataset in a `.tde` if you would like to use that. [vgsales.tde](https://github.com/vizyourdata/files/blob/master/vgsales.tde)

**Edit: Thinking regional settings might be a factor.**

Click the dropdown on the right of the data source. Select `Text File Properties`

[image]

To get this window:

[image]

Can you match these settings?

Comment: Running this specific dataset isn't exactly the problem, since I can convert it to an excel and then run on tableau, but every .csv I try to open gets the same result. I do tried open it first on Tableau but doesn't solved the problem

Comment: If you take the original csv and change it to a .txt, what happens? I just downloaded the original csv from kaggle and Tableau doesn't have any problem with it being a.csv or .txt. You mentioned using a trial version but that won't have any impact on functionality. The trial version is the full product.

Comment: **Edited for `Text File Properties` check